# Read search query in current fragment without launching activity

Tags: android, searchview

I am building an app which contains a signle `Activity` which contains an `ActionBar`. The activity contains a tab host with 4 tabs and each can be searched for something else, depending on the tab and fragment that is displayed.

According to the developer guide (https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html#add-sv), when pressing the search button after the user has entered his query, the activity will be launched with a search intent in which I can read the query like this:

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) 
{
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        //use the query to search your data somehow
}
```

However, I don't want to relaunch the activity, then decide which fragment raised the query, set the tabs to the correct one, constructing a new fragment and so on... What I want to do is simply read the query itself inside the fragment which the user type in (I noticed that the `SearchView` class got a `getQuery` method).

How can I somehow implement a listener that reads the query after the user has finished writing his query and pressed the search button in the virtual keyboard without recreating the activity? I want to just get a reference to the search box and use it like it's a TextView, read it's text and use it.

Comment: read SearchView docs before asking

Comment: OnQueryTextListener is just an interface that lets you listen for entered text, how can it send an intent?

Comment: do you use searchable config or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I eventually did was implementing `OnQueryTextListener`. This listener got 2 methods: `onQueryTextChange` which is called on every key pressed with the text as the parameter, and `onQueryTextSubmit` which is invoked when the user presses the search button. If you return `true` in `onQueryTextSubmit`, it means that everything is handled and there is no need to launch an intent.